# Tabbed terminal that connects to a GNU Screen session?

Tags: terminal, shell, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal

I use the session feature of screen extensively.  For example, I'll start a screen session for "project1" as "screen -S project1", and then when I need to reconnect I use "screen -d -r project1".  This makes it easy to manage multiple projects, each with their own set of shell sessions.

What I would love to do now is that when running on Windows and Linux, to be able to use a tabbed terminal program (such as gnome-terminal) to connect to a screen session and have all of the screen windows split out to separate tabs.  This way I get all the usual power of screen, but with the convenience of a richer GUI experience.

Is there any such terminal program available on Windows and/or Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at **byobu** its screen but with massive enhancements, You would still use one terminal but you get tabbed sessions so you can skip though the diffrent screens using the function keys. plus it gives you an nice dashboard.

[image]

Comment: byobu seems like a good solution to the question. However if you happen to use Putty this might come in handy: [byobu-function-keys-do-not-work-in-putty](https://codeyarns.com/2013/01/21/byobu-function-keys-do-not-work-in-putty/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have $SCREENDIR defined or change it in the command line to the directory where screen session sockets are. This is how you can do it easily in bash shell:

```
screens=( $(ls $SCREENDIR | sed 's/^[0-9]\+\.\(.*\)$/--tab -t \"\1\" -e \"screen -d -r \1\"/') ); eval gnome-terminal ${screens[@]}
```

If you don't want to close previous screen sessions (together with gnome-terminal if these are the only tabs) then use shared sessions with "-x" instead of "-d -r"

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing when I came across your question.  So far my search has hinted that eterm contains some (incomplete?) integration called Escreen.  I just installed it and it appears to work ok, though I'm having some trouble with key bindings (home doesn't go to home).  The theme doesn't match the rest of the desktop either.

Hope it helps.

[image: screenshot with 3 screen "tabs"]